# Responder perguntas antigas, porém sem respostas

Tags: debate, perguntas, perguntas-sem-resposta

Há várias perguntas antigas, enviadas a pelo menos um mês, chegando a seis meses, porém sem respostas, com nenhum ou poucos comentários.

É recomendado responder esse tipo de pergunta? Pois elas me parecem "abandonadas", porém muitas delas são de conteúdos que eu sei, e eu não tenho muitas chances de ganhar espaço no site a não ser por elas, pois o conteúdo novo é muito concorrido.

Compensa responder essas perguntas tendo em vista que os criadores já podem ter resolvido ou nunca vão voltar ao site?

Comment: Claro que compensa! Existem até [duas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/64/revival) [medalhas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) pra isso rsrs. É possível que o autor da pergunta não esteja mais ativo no site e não possa se beneficiar da resposta (caso em que a pergunta permaneceria sem o aceite), mas outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida se beneficiarão.

Comment: P.S. Esqueci de comentar, mas até mesmo as perguntas antigas *com resposta* (aceita ou não) podem se beneficiar de uma resposta adicional que seja melhor, mais completa, mais atualizada, que ofereça uma perspectiva distinta, etc. O StackOverflow [não é um fórum](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/215), mas [uma mistura de fórum, blog, wiki etc](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92122/177950), de modo que se você possui algo a acrescentar, que agregue valor para os usuários futuros, sua contribuição é muito bem vinda.

Comment: E editar a pergunta ou a resposta também! E votar, positivo ou negativo, também! Basicamente, seja uma pergunta recente ou dos primórdios, sempre faça tudo que possa melhorar o conteúdo. ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Fantástico!**

O arquivo de perguntas sem resposta é uma mina de ouro para encontrar problemas interessantes e para ganhar uns pontos eventuais.

Tem possibilidade de ganhar pontos porque:

- a pergunta vai parar na primeira página ao receber uma nova resposta;
- talvez o AP (autor da pergunta) siga frequentando o site e goste da resposta;
- daqui a 5 meses algum outro usuário topa com sua solução e, como ajuda muito, faz o obrigado do jeito Stack Overflow: dando +1.

Além disso, aumentará seu próprio conhecimento sobre o assunto ao resolver tais problemas interessantes, e reforçará o conhecimento já adquirido ao responder perguntas triviais.

E, ainda mais, o site também ganha porque aumenta a porcentagem de perguntas respondidas.

E, como [comentou @mgibsonbr](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4576/responder-perguntas-antigas-por%C3%A9m-sem-respostas#comment14698_4576), um desafio maior ainda é responder perguntas já resolvidas/respondidas. Nesses casos, vai ver respostas de alta qualidade e o desafio é escrever uma ainda melhor. Pode ter certeza, que com o passar dos meses/anos, se a resposta for boa mesmo, vai acumular votos suficientes para subir junto com as melhores.

Comment: e, se me permitem, uma resposta m[i](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58404/please-add-an-%C3%9Cber-fanatic-badge/157449#157449)nha depois de 2 anos da pergunta e que já ultrapassou o *boss* :p

Answer (score 13):

Sim, embora exista a chance do usuário que fez a pergunta já ter resolvido o problema, ter tirado a dúvida em algum outro lugar ou até mesmo não ser mais ativo aqui no site, é sempre bom responder todas as perguntas, pois no futuro essa sua resposta poderá vir a ajudar outras pessoas que talvez encontrem a pergunta através de uma pesquisa numa ferramenta de busca por exemplo.

E mesmo que o usuário que realizou a pergunta não marque sua reposta como a correta, você ainda poderá ganhar pontos de outros usuários que encontrarem a sua resposta e até mesmo medalhas.

Tente se colocar no lugar de alguém que está com uma dúvida e realiza uma pesquisa no Google, dentre os resultados dessa pesquisa você encontra um link para uma pergunta no Stack Overflow, essa pergunta tem uma resposta ótima e que te ajuda a resolver sua dúvida. Isso é ótimo não é?. E muitas das vezes esse usuário irá dar um *upvote* na sua resposta e você irá ganhar aqueles pontos virtuais que todos aqui adoram.

Comment: Realmente. Inclusive considerando que tem usuário que some por um tempão, mas acaba voltando, mesmo depois de muitos meses! ... :P

Comment: @Bacco ...senti uma indireta pra mim....

Comment: só por isso, tome um +1 na resposta. (ok, não é só por isso, é que eu concordo mesmo, mas esqueci de votar ontem).